# Call Powershell script from PHP

Tags: php, powershell

I have a code to call a powershell script by passing two array arguments using php . But when i call the function it's not returning the value to UI

```
<form method="post" action="Index.php">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" onClick="CallPowershell" value="Generate Report" />
</form>
```

The Below methos is used to call Powershell script

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo shell_exec('C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe  C:\\Users\\CallPower.ps1');
    }
```

and this is Powershell script(CallPower.ps1)

```
New-Item C:\Users\test.txt
Set-Content C:\Users\test.txt 'Welcome to TutorialsPoint'
```

and here i have print all VMNames in UI . But it is not displaying anything .

Comment: Start debugging by running the ps1 manually with the same account PHP uses. Does it work? If it does, change it to write a temp file and try running it again. If temp file gets created, try invoking the script via PHP. Does the temp file get created? If yes, it's about reading Powershell output. If not, it's something about executing the ps1.

Comment: no i tried that . when executing manually it gets created , but not when calling using PHP @vonPryz

Comment: Did you impersonate the service account PHP is running as?

Comment: NO ,i didn't @vonPryz

Comment: Well, do that. Then _edit the question_ and explain what happened during the impersonation attempt.

Comment: How to do that , Can You please explain @vonPryz

Comment: Use your favorite search engine to find out, or try a few different ones. Some keywords worth of trying are `runas` and `impersonate`. Searching the web is a critical skill for any developer, so consider this as a learning opportunity - not as being condescending.

Comment: @ThanmayaRaj your powershell script doesn't declare any parameters and never consume `$args` or `$input` - for all we know the parameter arguments are being passed just fine, you just don't do anything with them